# How to flush cache for IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: iis, cache, windows

Hope someone can help me with this.

I have PHP successfully installed via Fast-CGI for IIS 7.5 on WS2008 R2.

Let's say i try to edit some file called **about.php** and save it. If i check the changes via localhost, it works perfectly from the server.

However, if i try to see the changes using another computer and using the IP address of the site http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX i can't see the changes. The file remains the same before editing. I've deleted my browser cache and that is not the problem. It remains the same.

Im used to work with Linux/Apache combo but this time i have to use IIS so i don't know how caching works here. What should i do to flush the cache of IIS for me to be able to see all the changes i make to the site?

Using RDP and checking `http://localhost` works good. If i check it using a regular browser, regular internet connection and everything, i can't see the changes so im asumming something is keeping a cache.

Hope i've explained well. Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Stop and restart the World Wide Web Publishing service on the server... or alternately... run iisreset /restart from a command prompt on the server and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Noup, already tried that. Same thing :( where does IIS stores temp files? must be a folder right?

Comment: U sure it's IIS cacheing it?  What browser are you using?

Comment: All three major browsers do the same. Inside the server it shows the updated versions, but if i try via domain.com it still show the old versions of the htmls and phps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: So weird. I restarted the instance two times and now everything is working :)

Comment: I'm glad your problem went away, [but that's not really an answer](http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/06/09/press-the-green-button-twice/) -- From what you're describing it sounds like local browser caches (did you restart the browser after dumping the cache?), or if you're using a "PHP Accelerator" that could be the culprit too...

Comment: Glad you've sorted this. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.